# Error loading code into PIC with K150 programmer

Tags: pic

I'm new in pic programming.I wrote a LED lighting program with CCS. I threw this program into proteus and checked if it works. It was working properly.When trying to send the code I wrote for the PIC to the PIC using the k150 programmer I get the following errors.The PIC is 16F84A.

[image: First Error]

[image: Reset Failed]